Lubuntu desktop (LXQT) desktop icon spacing way too wide when locale is set to Taiwan(zh_tw)
Recently I install LXQT desktop on my Ubuntu WSL2 but the desktop icon spacing is way too wide, when locale is set to Taiwan(zh_tw), is there any way to adjust the spacing?
I've tried to adjust the desktop prefence but still cannot narrow down the spacing.
The only way I can resolve it is to set locale to UnitedStates(en_us), I'm wondering why this is happening? Any workaround or tips is appreciated.
